# 404 error after adding Content-Encoding as request header

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, httpwebrequest, content-encoding

I have to add Content-Encoding and Accept-Encoding as headers(with gzip compression) to `HttpWebRequest` object. Setting Accept-Encoding is done by adding this line: `request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;` and it is ok. However, after setting Content-Encoding(which i'm not sure whether it is done correctly) with this line `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");`, i get 404 error. Here is my request code:

```
XmlDocument RequestAndResponseHelper(string requestStr, string directory)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(directory);

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestStr);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";

    request.Headers.Add("userName", UserName);  
    request.Headers.Add("password", Password); 

    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip; //this adds  'Accept-Encoding: gzip' as request header
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip"); //this adds 'Content-Encoding: gzip' as request header

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    XmlDocument rs = new XmlDocument();
    rs.LoadXml(responseString);

    return rs;
}
```

If you can help me to handle with that error, i'd really appreciate.

Also, here is my compression code, maybe there is something with compression.

```
String Compress(String requestStr)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestStr);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    { zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); }
    ms.Position = 0;
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);
    byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest check your request uri. You will get a 404 only if your request uri is wrong. Either the resource does not exist on the server or your server is down.

if you had given a wrong value elsewhere in the headers like the ContentEncoding, means the origin server is not supporting the encoding, you get different error codes..here a 415 (unsupported) but not 404.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if my request uri was wrong wouldn't i get 404 error without that line `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");`

Answer (score 1):

The wrong header field is being set to "gzip".

`ContentEncoding` relates to character types in the data before any gzipping etc is done. It has values denoting encodings such as "Ascii", "UTF7", "UTF32", etc. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.contentencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx).

"Gzip" is a MIME type specified via a `HttpRequestHeader.ContentType`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype.aspx).

Comment: Actually, based on some search, i deduce similar thought like that. However, my service provider exactly says that "The following line should be added to the HTTP header:
Content-Encoding: gzip". Then i thought that there should be some way to pass this as header.

Comment: Then should i embed gzip statement in this line of my code: `request.ContentType = "text/xml";` ?